# Resource leaks in the factory pattern

Tags: java, factory, resource-leak

Suppose you have a `Car` class implementing `AutoCloseable`. The constructor takes an `Engine` object that needs to be stopped when the car is closed.

```java
class Car implements AutoCloseable
{
    final Engine engine;

    Car(final Engine engine)
    {
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
    {
        engine.stop();
    }
}
```

A `CarFactory` first initializes an engine, then uses it to construct a new car.

```java
class CarFactory
{
    public Car createCar()
    {
        // Initialize resources
        final Engine engine = new Engine();
        engine.start();

        // Pass them to a closeable object
        return new Car(engine);
    }
}
```

The car is ensured to be closed in a try-with-resources statement.

```java
try (final Car car = carFactory.createCar())
{
    // drive around
}
```

But what if `Engine#start()` raised an exception? Then the factory call never completes, the engine isn't stopped and therefore the resources it had taken up aren't released.

Now my usual fix has been to just move the whole initialisation logic out of the factory method and into the try-with-resources block:

```java
class CarFactory
{
    public Car createCar()
    {
        return new Car(new Engine());
    }
}
```

```java
try (final Car car = carFactory.createCar())
{
    car.engine.start();

    // drive around
}
```

This, however, has lead to a lot of duplicate code, especially when different car implementations share similar initialisation logic. Besides that, it just feels wrong; I'd expect the initialisation to happen in the factory. Can you help me find a better solution?

Comment: If `Engine#start()` raises an exception it should not be started!

Comment: The point is that `new Engine()` already allocates resources that aren't released until it is stopped.

Comment: If `new Engine()` allocates resources, then it should itself be an `AutoCloseable` and thus should be treated inside a try-with-resources statement.

Comment: @aic34127 If `start();` is raising an exception, why do you need to stop it to release the resources? It shouldn't be in the state "started" since there was an exception in the `start();` method. Also, what resources are allocated in `new Engine()` which aren't cleaned up? Keep in mind that the object will be GCed since it isn't used anymore.

Comment: you should consider using a finally block. Its purpose is exactly to release resources allocated during a try block no matter what exceptions were raised